# Is the new profile style on SE coming to Physics SE?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design, profile-page

I've noticed that other stack exchange sites have a [new style of user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244238/). The new style has a different layout, as well as more statistics, such as ["people reached"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534/), which is interesting. Is the new style coming to physics?

My profile pages on other stack exchange sites have the new template, but my physics one doesn't.

Comment: I'm putting my money on Physics being the 9th last to get it. So when we get it, there should be 8 left without it. Shall we start a pool?

Comment: Can I point out that there are currently 9 sites without the update. If my guess is right, we will be next

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/DNqR19x.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/WUVCeH3.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/3ZYgwRc.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/mkLHMUD.png

what a long journey it has been

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(Edited to reflect the current situation) We now have the new CSS and profile page layout.

Prior to this, nobody knew when it was coming (except *maybe* the design team, but I'm not sure if their scheduling algorithm is any more sophisticated than "what site do we feel like working on today?"). There is/was [a list of sites which have had the update and those which have not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed), but it was kept in random order without any indication of when the remaining sites would get their design update.

Comment: It seems the "On Deck" sites are on something like a six-to-eight-weeks timeline. Which is to say, "at some point in the future".